# Syntax error with sum in sql code

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having issues with my SQL Server code. I am trying to get results to list by the first 4 columns of the select statement. I keep getting syntax errors and am unsure as to why.

What I want it to do is pull by the entityid, acctnum, period that I define but, I don't want to see the period in the results as I want them to be summed together. IE I want see the total activity for the activity column instead of rows for each period.

```
SELECT 
    ENTITYID, ACCTNUM, ACCTNAME, ACTIVITY
FROM
    (SELECT  
         g.ENTITYID AS 'ENTITYID'
         g.ACCTNUM AS 'ACCTNUM'
         SUM(g.ACTIVITY) AS 'ACTIVITY'
         h.ACCTNAME AS 'ACCTNAME'
     FROM 
         SQLDATA.DBO.GLSUM  g
     INNER JOIN 
         SQLDATA.DBO.GACC h ON g.ACCTNUM = h.ACCTNUM
     WHERE   
         g.ENTITYID = '85000'
         g.PERIOD < '201703'
         g.ACCTNUM = '569300000')
```

Comment: Are you going to share the error message with us?  You are missing a closing ) somewhere.

Comment: There is an error in the SQL Statement, Incorrect syntax near 'g'

Comment: Looks like you are missing a closed parenthesis.

Comment: you query is not even complete

Comment: Shouldn't you close the "(" you opened after FROM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a GROUP BY clause https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql, commas in the SELECT list, AND keywords between WHERE elements, and the outer select seems a bit redundant.

```
SELECT  
    g.ENTITYID AS 'ENTITYID',
    g.ACCTNUM AS 'ACCTNUM',
    SUM(g.ACTIVITY) AS 'ACTIVITY',
    h.ACCTNAME AS 'ACCTNAME'
FROM 
    SQLDATA.DBO.GLSUM  g
INNER JOIN 
    SQLDATA.DBO.GACC h ON g.ACCTNUM = h.ACCTNUM
WHERE   
    g.ENTITYID = '85000'
    AND g.PERIOD < '201703'
    AND g.ACCTNUM = '569300000' 
GROUP BY  
    g.ENTITYID,
    g.ACCTNUM,
    h.ACCTNAME
```

Comment: I still get the same "There is an error in the SQL statement, Incorrect syntax near 'g'."

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @a int 
SET @a = select sum(g.ACTIVITY) 
         from SQLDATA.DBO.GLSUM  
         WHERE ENTITYID = '85000' and
               PERIOD < '201703' and
               ACCTNUM = '569300000' 



SELECT  

           g.ENTITYID AS 'ENTITYID'
           g.ACCTNUM AS 'ACCTNUM'
           @a AS 'ACTIVITY'
           h.ACCTNAME AS 'ACCTNAME'

FROM SQLDATA.DBO.GLSUM  g
INNER JOIN SQLDATA.DBO.GACC h
ON g.ACCTNUM = h.ACCTNUM

WHERE   

           g.ENTITYID = '85000'
           g.PERIOD < '201703'
           g.ACCTNUM = '569300000'
```